# Is it possible to add jQuery functionality inside a regular Javascript function?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a gridview that displays a summary for each product. When a user clicks on one row, I want him to see a jQuery dialog that displays details on the product whose row was clicked.

The web framework is ASP.NET, so below is how the `<td>` element looks like in the browser source

```
<td id="_ctl0_contentMain_gvListOfProducts__ctl13_cRef" align="left"
onclick="getProductInfo(10244);" style="width:10%;cursor:pointer;">Sneakers</td>
```

I have also a div that's is supposed to be used for the dialog

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function getProductInfo(id) {
       //TO DO: Add jQuery functionality here to display dialog
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Yes it is possible. jQuery is regular javascript.

Comment: just make sure you have a reference to jquery on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only thing you need is to give a unique id and a class to each row, and then call one the jquery functions to load the product detail....

```
    $('.row').live('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var id = this.id;


                return false;
            });
```

above code bind a click event for every row with "row" class and then as you can see, you can grab it is id and do what ever you want...

Comment: Do I need to add the above code inside the getProductInfo function? In fact, it's not an HTML id but rather the id of the product that needs to displayed.

Comment: As you already declared you pass the id to the function, so you should call your function after "var id = this.id;"

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course.  jQuery *is* JavaScript